# Is there any Java based page object framework similar to Taza?

Tags: selenium, java, test-automation-framework, page-objects, ruby

This is probably not a typical SO question. But, I need to post this here because google searches have not given me the answer I was looking for. Hopefully, the experienced developers here can give some quick suggestions.

Can someone please suggest a easy & intuitive, java based, page object testing framework which is similar to the Taza framework in ruby ?

Taza :https://github.com/scudco/taza/wiki

> SYNOPSIS
>
> Taza is meant to be a refreshing way to look at browser testing. Taza provides a few ways to abstract browser-based testing into three simple ideas.
>
> - Sites
> - Pages
> - Flows
>
> Sites have Pages.
>   Pages have Elements and Filters.
>   Flows are common actions on a site such as logging in or performing a search.

Answer (score 1):

The Taza framework cannot be called a page object based framework, but Arquillian Graphene can be, as its concept is the same, as the Page object model has. And it makes sense using it, if pages of the application, you write your tests for, have a number of elements with widgets, grids, tables and so on.
Besides looking for and selecting a particular framework, I would recommend researching into CI solutions and reporting about test results. There are well know instruments for that task (Jenkins one of them) and number of manuals can be easily found. One of them is [how to automate testing, using selenium, webdriver, jenkins and Allure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-automate-testing-using-selenium-webdriver-jenkins-and-allure)

Comment: Thanks. So, what kind of framework is Taza if its not page object ? Is there any Java framework which is similar to Taza ?

Answer (score 0):

I do not have much idea about Taza.

I have been using Arquillian Graphene framework for Selenium webdriver testing.

Take a look at below posts to know more about them. It has a page object injection at run time, creating page objects with page fragments (similar to modules in taza)

http://www.testautomationguru.com/selenium-webdriver-automation-using-arquillian-framework/

http://www.testautomationguru.com/arquillian-graphene-page-fragments/

Answer (score 0):

*(Please delete if this answer doesn't meet community guidelines.)*

If I may, I'd like to introduce you to my own Cucumber+Selenium based framework called [Kheera](http://kheera.in).

The interesting thing about Kheera is that it lets you test really complicated flows without writing a single line of code. As you automate a web page, your feature files become executable scripts.

Under the covers, it still relies on the familiar page object model but the entire scripting and script maintenance process is much faster because you aren't writing boilerplate code.